# Accessing UILabel Outlet without user interaction

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm having an issue with an iPhone app I'm working on.

It uses a separate class called Radio which streams a station in. When the title of the stream is updated, it calls back to RadioViewController with the method updateTitle:

```
- (void)updateTitle:(NSString *)newTitle
{
    NSLog(@"update title called with title: %@", newTitle);
    [self.nowPlaying setText:newTitle];
}
```

For some reason, I can't seem to get nowPlaying to update. If I call setText from viewDidLoad, then it works fine.

Also, with any sort of user interaction, whether a button or something else, the text changes fine, as in:

```
- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender
{
[self.nowPlaying setText:@"now playing test"];
}
```

nowPlaying is linked up in the XIB and setup as such:

```
    IBOutlet    UILabel     *nowPlaying;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *nowPlaying;
```

And updateTitle is setup as

```
- (void)updateTitle:(NSString *)title;
```

The code builds and runs fine, without error. But the UILabel is just not changing.

Comment: So does updateTitle get called at all (i.e. do you see that log message)?  If not, you should look upstream in the RadioViewController to make sure that code path is being reached.

Comment: Yes, the log message is outputted. Also, I have multiple views setup, it that changes anything.

Comment: That's pretty mysterious... are you by any chance calling updateTitle from a secondary thread?

Comment: Have you checked that `self.nowPlaying` isn't nil?  Try having an extra `NSLog` for that.  Maybe the bindings hasn't occurred yet by the time the method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set the title, NSLog the self.nowPlaying.title to make sure it's changed.

You may need an explicit `[self.nowPlaying setNeedsDisplay];` to force an update.

If not, do the normal debugging to make sure that self.nowPlaying is a real object, etc.  Are you sure nowPlaying is connected to the right label in IB?

Comment: Looks like self.nowPlaying was nil. 
Apparently I was creating another instance of it instead of using the current instance so the UILabel was never created.
Thanks for mentioning that!

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your updateTitle method as follows:

```
NSLog(@"Update title will update %@ with %@", self.nowPlaying, newTitle);
[self.nowPlaying performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:newTitle waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I have a feeling you are updating the title on a background thread which is not supported in many use cases.